# Как вернуть значения по курсору

Tags: c#, access, база-данных

Доброго времени суток!
Нижеуказанный код возвращает первую запись в наборе записей из таблицы Test:

```
...
com.Connection = conn;
com.CommandText = "Select * from Test";
OleDbDataReader myOleDbDataReader = com.ExecuteReader(); 
myOleDbDataReader.Read();
testDialog.textBox1.Text = myOleDbDataReader.GetString(1);
testDialog.numericUpDown1.Value = myOleDbDataReader.GetInt32(2);
testDialog.textBox2.Text = myOleDbDataReader.GetString(3);
...
```

Как добиться того, чтобы значение возвращало по курсору запись, а не первую запись таблицы, без циклов?

Answer (score 1):

`OleDbDataReader.Read` возвращает `bool`. Он возвращает `true`, если запись прочитана, и `false`, если набор данных закончился. Для работы с этим объектом нужно организовать условный цикл, а обращения к полям текущей строки набора данных делать внутри цикла.

Кроме того, использование `OleDbDataReader` следует оборачивать блоком `using`, чтобы вовремя освобождать соединение.

Comment: Хорошо, а как получить значения полей на которых стоит курсор (не первая, а текущая запись). В делфи на этот счет есть грамотное решение. Как обстоит дело с c#. Про реадер написал просто для разьяснения ситуации, если есть решение без него, буду рад услышать ответ.

Comment: Где у Вас стоит курсор? В самом MS Access или в Вашей программе с гридом?

Comment: В программе с гридом

Comment: Тогда Вам вообще не нужно заново подключаться, Вам нужно обратиться к гриду и получить его текущую строку 
`dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem` 

Насколько я помню, она имеет тип `DataRowView`, у которого есть индексатор для обращения к полям.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать. Вопрос только такой, как идет присвоение значения определенного поля? Например, как textBox1.text присвоить первый столбец таблицы?

Comment: Не через набор данных разве это проще делать, чем через непосредственно сам грид?

Comment: А как Вы в наборе данных узнаете, что пользователь выделил в гриде? Эту информацию можно получить только от грида.